# MySQL optimise query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
SELECT 
    (UserCourseProgress.TimeEnded - UserCourseProgress.TimeStarted) as SecondsSpent,
    UserCourseProgress.UserId 
FROM 
    UserCourseProgress 
    INNER JOIN UserRoles 
    ON UserCourseProgress.UserId = UserRoles.UserId 
       AND (UserRoles.SuperId = '123' OR UserRoles.UserId = '123')
```

I'm trying to optimise this query as it takes too long (mainly Copying Data To Tmp Table).
The structure is simple a table called `UserCourseProgress` and another one called `UserRoles`, they both have the `UserId` column in common and I'm selecting all `userRoles` that belong to a super user. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on `UserRoles.SuperId` and `UserRoles.UserId`, as well as on the FK `UserCourseProgress.UserId`

Comment: can you give the table structure ,and little more explanation,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use UNION**

```
SELECT
    (UserCourseProgress.TimeEnded - UserCourseProgress.TimeStarted) as SecondsSpent,
    UserCourseProgress.UserId FROM UserCourseProgress 
INNER JOIN UserRoles ON UserCourseProgress.UserId = UserRoles.UserId
    AND UserRoles.SuperId = '123'

UNION

SELECT
    (UserCourseProgress.TimeEnded - UserCourseProgress.TimeStarted) as SecondsSpent,
    UserCourseProgress.UserId FROM UserCourseProgress 
INNER JOIN UserRoles ON UserCourseProgress.UserId = UserRoles.UserId
    AND UserRoles.UserId = '123';
```

**Add INDEX**

```
ALTER TABLE UserCourseProgress ADD INDEX (UserId);
ALTER TABLE UserRoles ADD INDEX (SuperId, UserId);
ALTER TABLE UserRoles ADD INDEX (UserId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use EXPLAIN to obtain the query execution plan. Then, look the more consuming steps and use index if necessary.

[EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/explain.html)